# Parallax Scrolling in website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have learn something about parallax scrolling.

```
    Parallax scrolling is a special scrolling technique in computer graphics, wherein background  
     images move by the camera slower than foreground images, creating an illusion of depth in a 2D  
   video game and adding to the immersion.
```

Many websites uses it and they code it using javascript.

Can any one give a code example of it?

Tutorial was held recently by Google GDay.

Comment: Tutoria http://richardshepherd.com/smashing/parallax/background.html

Comment: Actually there are *lots* of tutorials. A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=parallax+scrolling+tutorial) returned about 200,000 results.

Answer (score 3):

There are several js libraries available that provide parallax effects.  I have personally used [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/) for projects before, but you should probably do some research as to what other libraries are available and best suit your needs.

Regardless of what you choose, the basic idea is that the parallax elements on your page use fixed or absolute css positioning, so that they actually don't respond to scrolling directly (they're locked to the window or a parent element).  This also allows the designer to precisely define the start locations of these elements.  Functions are then defined to control the movement of each parallax element by responding to javascript scroll events and updating the elements' left and top values as needed.

I've made a really simple example of parallax movement [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zG3aC/):

### HTML

```
<div id="downparallax" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;">Hello world!
    <br/>I move in parallax!</div>
<div id="rightparallax" style="position:fixed;left:0;top:50%;">I move right when you scroll down!</div>
```

### js

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    document.getElementById("downparallax").style.bottom = window.scrollY / 2.0 + "px";
    document.getElementById("rightparallax").style.left = window.scrollY + "px";
}
```